# AS3: Loading images from facebook servers

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, actionscript, loader

I'm building a Flass Application for Facebook, and I'm trying to load some user images from facebook, with their url (they're given to me through flashvars from a php)... The problem is that, while I'm testing it inside Flash, it works like a charm, but when I upload it to the FTP server, it stops working...

I have this on the Stage intialization:

```
flashvars = this.loaderInfo.parameters;
        // constructor code
        if (flashvars.imgUrl != null)
        {
            imgUrl = flashvars.uid;
        }
        else {
            imgUrl = 'https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/1240107_10201576612713442_1154772803_n.jpg';
            //imgUrl = 'imagen_test.jpg';
        }
        loadImg(imgUrl);
```

And this further down, on my function definitions...

```
public function loadImg(str:String):void {
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(str);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,_cargaFoto);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,_loadError);
        Security.loadPolicyFile("http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml");
        loader.load(urlReq);
    }
    public function _loadError(e:IOErrorEvent) {
        ExternalInterface.call('console.log',e.type);
    }
    public function _cargaFoto(e:Event) {
        ExternalInterface.call('console.log','it loaded just fine');

        miBm = e.target.content;
        trace(miBm.width);
        bmWidth = miBm.width;
        bmHeight = miBm.height;
        //addChild(miBm);
        getContext(Context3DRenderMode.AUTO); // this starts other part of the code...
    }
```

I'm not getting any IO_ERRORS either, so I don't actually know what's going on.. can anybody give me a hand over here? Thanks a lot in advance!

** EDIT **

The image seems to be loading, it triggers the event that logs 'it loaded just fine', but when I try to use it (I even tried with an addChild of the Bitmap) it won't work.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Do you get any security error events (`SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR`)? You are loading the crossdomain file from a different (sub)domain than where the image is hosted. Also beware that images from Facebook won't necessarily all be on the same server and they may move over time.

Comment: I managed to fix this! It was a matter of adding a context with policyfiles to the loader. Once I did that, it started working just fine!